# setting http.HandleFunc in loop adds all routes but return function is that of last element

Tags: loops, go, http

So I'm trying to learn Go but I'm having a bit of trouble understanding what is happening here. I have a .json file with some "routes" defined that I want to pass into `http.HandleFunc` in a loop and when I do, it does creates the route, but the return value is that of the last item in the map. I'm setting the return with an anonymous function.

This is my server.go:

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "net/http"
    "os"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {
    dat, err := os.ReadFile("routes.json")
    check(err)

    routes := dat
    var result map[string]any

    json.Unmarshal([]byte(routes), &result)

    http.HandleFunc("/test", func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        io.WriteString(w, "Hello test! \n")
    })

    for key, element := range result {
        fmt.Println("Key:", key, "=>", "return:", element.(map[string]interface{})["return"])

        http.HandleFunc(key, func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
            io.WriteString(w, element.(map[string]interface{})["return"].(string))
        })
    }

    fmt.Println("Starting webserver")
    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

This is my routes.json

```
{
    "/default": {
        "return": "This is the default response"
    },
    "/another": {
        "return": "This is another response"
    }
}
```

Now when I send a request to "**http://localhost:8080/test**" (defined statically before the loop), I get the correct response: "**Hello test!**"
but when I request a route in the map, i.e.:
**http://localhost:8080/default** or **http://localhost:8080/another**
I always get the reponse "**This is another response**".

I was expecting "**/default**" to return "**This is the default response**"

Can anyone help with some links to documentation or concepts I might've missed?

Comment: You can fix the problem with `element := element` (i.e. by creating a _new_ variable) right at the top of the loop's body.

Comment: The problem occurs because `range` loops __reuse__ their iteration variables (e.g. the loop above _allocates_ only __one__ `key` and only __one__ `element`, and then, before executing each iteration the variables' values are updated to the current iteration values), this means that if you retain these iteration variables (like you do with the closure), that variable will, at the end of the loop, contain the last value of the loop, and ALL code referencing that variable (i.e. ALL closures) will __see that last value__.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204355/how-to-write-http-handlefunc-dynamically-in-golang

Answer (score 1):

Answered by mkopriva in a comment:

> You can fix the problem with element := element (i.e. by creating a
> new variable) right at the top of the loop's body.
>
> The problem occurs because range loops reuse their iteration variables
> (e.g. the loop above allocates only one key and only one element, and
> then, before executing each iteration the variables' values are
> updated to the current iteration values), this means that if you
> retain these iteration variables (like you do with the closure), that
> variable will, at the end of the loop, contain the last value of the
> loop, and ALL code referencing that variable (i.e. ALL closures) will
> see that last value.
>
> related:
> [How to write http.HandleFunc() dynamically in golang?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49204355/how-to-write-http-handlefunc-dynamically-in-golang)